# Multiple View Rendering issue in Spring Boot

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I am using Spring Boot application. In that i have used Spring MVC at front end. I have a requirement to download various reports like pdf, xls. As i understand, Spring Boot, internally uses ContentNegotiatingViewResolver, BeanNameViewResolver, ViewResolverComposite and InternalResourceViewResolver. I am not overriding any beans in code and using default configurations as provided

Currently to test, i am using below url

```
http://localhost:8080/SearchCustomers.xls
```

Properties in application.properties file are

```
spring.mvc.media-types.pdf=application/pdf
spring.mvc.media-types.xls=application/vnd.ms-excel
```

In my code, i have created a view class which extends from `AbstractPdfView`.It is a spring bean and it's id is "SearchCustomers".Controller code returns "SearchCustomers" as a view name.

Whenever i execute above code, `ContentNegotiatingViewResolver` doesn't returns any view.`ContentNegotiatingViewResolver` internally uses `BeanNameViewResolver`, `ViewResolverComposite` and `InteralResourceViewRsolver` to resolve view names.In our case, the bean name matches with view but its media type doesn't as it matches the path extension internally along with the bean content type.This is a correct Behavior?

However `DispatcherServlet` reiterates through all view resolvers and which is causing an issue.

In the second iteration, `BeanNameViewResolver` matches the bean id with returned view name from controller and it invokes the pdf view,which i believe is incorrect.

Is there any workaround for this?

Comment: So you are requesting a `xls` and expecting a `pdf` view to be returned? How do you expect that to work...

Comment: No i am not expecting it should return pdf..my expectation is it should throw an error that no matching view found...instead it is returning pdf view

Answer (score 0):

I found out the solution

If you want just one controller method to handle all type of requests..then in that case your view should be given id in below format

id - viewname + path extension

Ex

My controller method returns view name as "SearchCustomers" for all type of request..

I have created different views for different requests like

1. @Component("SearchCustomers.pdf")
   class MyPdfView extends from AbstractPdfView

   2. @Component("SearchCustomer.xls")
      class MyExcelView extends from AbstractExcelView

Interanally, CNVR searches for these beans. and then it matches the mediatype/contenttype which returns the correct view